# Set Cellstyle of a org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell to boolean

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to write a boolean-value into an excel-cell, but instead of setting the cellStyle to "logic" the cellStyle will become "number" instead.

```
private void writeToDocument(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("testSheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(true);
}
```

I already tryied

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat([short s]);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

but no short s between 0 and 49 did the job.

Answer (score 3):

When appropriate overloaded version of `setCellValue` is used the cell types will be assigned automatically, for example

```java
cell.setCellValue(true);
System.out.println(cell.getCellType());
```

prints `BOOLEAN`

Checked on `org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.1`

Comment: This is the correct answer for current `apache poi`  versions. See [XSSFCell.setCellValue(boolean value)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java?view=markup#l272) and [HSSFCell.setCellValue(boolean value)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_1/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.java?view=markup#l753)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(lineNumber);
Cell cell = row.createCell(1, CellType.BOOLEAN);
```

This will create a cell styled to persist boolean.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem caused by the type of cell, because `Cell.setCellValue(boolean value)` sets correct cell type. You need an appropiate `CellStyle`.

First create a style with boolean formatting:

```
public CellStyle createBooleanCellStyle(Workbook workbook){
   var style = workbook.createCellStyle();
   var format = workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("BOOLEAN");
   style.setDataFormat(format);
   return style;
}
```

Then use this style in your cell:

```
public void set(Cell cell, boolean value, CellStyle  cellStyle){
    cell.setCellValue(value);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
}
```

Note: do not create new style for each cell, but create one style and reuse it.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code for Boolean value

```
 private void writeToDocument(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("testSheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN);
        cell.setCellValue((Boolean) true);
    }
```

Comment: `cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN);` is deprecated. The user either needs to use `True` or `False` as text or `0` or `1` as number.

Answer (score -1):

This is how to customize a date, potentially you may try it with boolean

```
final XSSFCellStyle date = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
date.setDataFormat(
    sheet.getWorkbook()
         .getCreationHelper()
         .createDataFormat()
         .getFormat(pattern)
);
cell = row.createCell(index);
cell.setCellStyle(date);
```